# jsoup / Java - how to append a nonbreaking space

Tags: java, jsoup

Calling `[Element].appendtext("&nbsp;")` causes the ampersand to be escaped and so the user sees the ampersand on the rendered HTML page.  I don't want the page to render the HTML code.

I actually do want the html page to render whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-breaking space can be written into a string literal using a Unicode escape sequence: `"\u00A0"`.

However, if you want *all* whitespace within an element to be rendered literally, consider using normal spaces but applying a CSS property such as `white-space: pre;`.

Comment: Thank you, I do not want all whitespace, I wanted an nbsp between some other stuff that is not whitespace :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source library called MgntUtils that has a feature that takes a regular String and creates a String for Html format where the String formatting will be preserved. I.e. all the spaces in the String will be replaced with non-breaking spaces and all the new lines will be replaced with 'br' tags. The advantage that if you just print your String as text non-braking spaces will look just like regular space and not as "\u00A0" or nbsp escape. You will, of course, see br tags, but still, your String will look by far more readable. Here is [JavaDoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml-java.lang.String-) for the method. I found it sometimes very convenient. The code would just look

```
String htmlFormattedStr = formatStringToPreserveIndentationForHtml(rawText);
```

The library Maven artifacts could be found [here](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) and the library itself as a Jar file as well as source code and JavaDoc can be found on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Here is the [link to the article](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/michaelgantman/2016/01/26/open-source-java-library-with-stacktrace-filtering-silent-string-parsing-and-version-comparison) about the library